# Why StorageFile.GetFilesAsync() crash in dll?

Tags: uwp

I have made a dll of UWP and using the `StorageFile.GetFilesAsync()` in it.

Here is the code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    StorageFolder SFolder = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
    try
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> SFile = await SFolder.GetFilesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
});
```

After I ran the program, it crashed with the exception:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

It seems I have no permission to access the file. However, I checked the UWP program which referenced the dll, the UWP program has already declared the Capabilities of Removable Storage yet. 
[image]
What's wrong with it? Would you please tell me how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: You may need to declare file type association and handle the specific file types you declare.

Comment: @kennyzx I want to make a custom FileOpenPicker to read the txt file in removable devices, and the FileOpenPicker is not a control so that I can't overwrite it. I can only write a usercontrol to do this. When I try to read the files name in the directory, it occurs this error.

Comment: @kennyzx What's more,I found a article maybe about what you said the file type association in https://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1197 . I think that is much more different from my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders.removabledevices#prerequisites) states, there are two prerequisites for using the `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` folder:

> To access the removable devices folder, you must:
>
> - In the app manifest, **specify the Removable Storage capability**.
> - In the app manifest, **register at least one File Type Association declaration**. This declaration explicitly indicates the file types
>     (extensions) that your app wants to access on the removable devices.
>     The app can only enumerate, create, or change files that have the file
>     types declared in the app manifest. For more info, see Handle file
>     activation.

According to your question, you have handled the first prerequisite, but you also need to satisfy the second - which is specifying the file types your app works with. This can be done in the `Package.appxmanifest` **Declarations** tab. There you select **File Type Associations** in the drop down and fill out the required fields.

The reason access to removable storage is limited to only the file types you specify is an additional security measure, so that the user can rest assured that the app does not do anything harmful. If you need full access to a file system location, you will need to use the built-in `FolderPicker` or use the [`broadFilesystemAccess` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) (which is however a restricted capability and it is verified during Microsoft Store certification, whether the app has actually a good reason to declare it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the File Type Associations in the Declarations tab, but I can't find any tutorial or guide of MSDN. Is there any tutorial can recommend? Thank you.

Comment: To properly fill out the declaration try following the docs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation#step-1-specify-the-extension-point-in-the-package-manifest

Comment: Thank you, let me try first.

Comment: Well, I tried and it works, never report an error yet. Thank you!

Comment: Great, happy coding :-) !